# MacOS Automator does not work with chromedriver selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, automator

I am trying to use selenium and automator together. I have a "Run shell script" action on my automator which runs the python script with selenium WebDriver using chrome. For some reason, I have gotten the script to work when I use the safari WebDriver but the python script does not run using the chrome WebDriver. This is the sample test script I am using:

```
# check if chromedriver exists
with open('output.txt','w+') as output:
    # activate headless mode
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=2560x1600')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver', options = chrome_options)

    link = 'https://www.google.com/?client=safari'
    driver.get(link)

    time.sleep(2)
    driver.save_screenshot('test.png')
    driver.quit()
```

I have done some debugging and it looks like the error occurs on this line: driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='chromedriver', options = chrome_options)

Any suggestion would help, thank you in advance.

EDIT: The script runs perfectly when I run it using terminal, but it doesn't run perfectly when I use automator's "Run Shell Script". If anyone has used automator with python selenium successfully, a review of what y'all did would be amazing.

EDIT: SOLVED! I started using the absolute path and it worked

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: It doesn't give me an error - that's the weird thing. The script by itself runs perfectly when I run it using terminal, but it doesn't run well when I use automator's "Run Shell Script". Let me know if you need anything else